# Limiting of include in sequelizejs

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to limit items included via include in sequelizejs. I tried:

```
model1.findOne({
    where: {id: id},
    include: [
         {
             model: model2,
             limit: 5 // doenst work
         }
     ]
})
```

I want only 5 items of model2 included. Any idea, if that is possible?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1897.